# Can't access to a semaphore using its pointer (I think I am using & wrong)

Tags: c, multithreading, function, pointers, pthreads

I am implementing a thread safe queue in C using semaphores. I could do it with mutexes which was way easier. Now I am trying with binary semaphores. But I do not know how to access to the semaphore in the critical part of the functions. Here is my code:

```
int queueEnqueue(queue* q, int value){
    int* value1;
    sem_getvalue(&(q->sem1),value1);
    printf("Value of semaphore is: %d\n", *value1); 
    sem_wait(&(q->sem1));
    if(!queueIsFull(q)){
        q->rear = (q->rear + 1) % q->capacity;
        q->array[q->rear] = value;
        q->size = q->size + 1;
        return(1);
    }
    sem_post(&(q->sem1));
    return(0);
}
```

```
queue* queueCreate(unsigned capacity){ 
    queue* q = malloc(sizeof(queue)); 
    q->capacity = capacity;
    q->size = 0;
    q->front = 0;
    q->rear = -1;
    q->array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*capacity);
    sem_t sem1;
    sem_init(&sem1,0,1);
    q->sem1=sem1;
    return q;
}
```

I get core dumped at this line: sem_getvalue(&(q->sem1),value1);. I am probably trying to access to unpermitted memory locations. This line is also problematic:

```
sem_wait(&(q->sem1));
```

Comment: You're passing an indeterminate pointer to `sem_getvalue`. That `value1` should be `int`, not `int*`, and you should pass it by `&value1` (and, of course, change your `printf` argument to remove the dereference operator that no longer makes sense).

Comment: Thank you! And how about sem_wait(&(q->sem1));

Comment: Which part of the `&` on `&value1` in my prior comment did you not get ? Regarding `sem_wait`, fix what I said in my prior comment *first*. The only thing I see odd in your semaphore setup is the initialization of a local `sem1`, then copy to the `q->sem1` member. That's somewhat pointless. Just initialize the `q->sem1` member directly via `sem_init(&q->sem1, 0,1);` and call it good. the local `sem1` isn't needed.

Comment: Your code invoked undefined behavior with that broken pointer passed to `sem_getvalue`. Once that happened, stop trying to make sense of what happened after; there is none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem with sem_getvalue is answered by WhozCraig.

The other problem regarding sem_wait/sem_post(&(q->sem1)); is sem_post is never reached since the program returns before